# Binding a DataGrid's CellTemplate content to an Element or a DependencyProperty defined on the templated CustomControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm using WPF's regular DataGrid inside a custom control.
One of the DataGrid's cell template content should be bound to a the Text of a Textblock or to a DependencyProperty on the custom control. (If I could bind it to any of them it's good enough for me)

I tried to do the following binding with the ElementName but it didn't work. I keep getting an DependencyProperty.UnsetValue -

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ContentPresenter>
                <ContentPresenter.Content>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextToSpecialTextblockConverter}">
                       <Binding Path="SomeTextOnTheViewModel"/>
                       <Binding ElementName="SearchBox" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </ContentPresenter.Content>
             </ContentPresenter>
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Binding to a DependencyProperty also doesn't work.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ContentPresenter>
                <ContentPresenter.Content>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextToSpecialTextblockConverter}">
                       <Binding Path="SomeTextOnTheViewModel"/>
                       <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" Path="SomeDP" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </ContentPresenter.Content>
             </ContentPresenter>
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I hope someone could help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: Is `SearchBox` defined before the `DataGrid`?

Comment: Yes it is defined before the DataGrid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the property `Property` is defined on a view model set on the `DataContext` of the control or `DataGrid` then this sample works:

Resources:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Property,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

DataGrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource template}" />
```

The DependencyProperty change notification could update the view model.

For example:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof (string), typeof (DataGridComboBoxColumn), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), PropertyChangedCallback));

    public string Test
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        ((MyControl) dependencyObject).OnTestChanged();
    }

    private void OnTestChanged()
    {
        ((MyViewModel) theGrid.DataContext).Property = Test;
    }
```

In order to bind to a dependency property `Test` using a template binding use this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="template2">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Test: "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomControl1}}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test" CellTemplate="{StaticResource template2}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Where CustomControl1 is

```
public class CustomControl1 : ItemsControl
{
    static CustomControl1()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof (CustomControl1),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (CustomControl1)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof (string), typeof (CustomControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Test
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Phil, thank you for your answer! But in my case there's no ViewModel, just a CustomControl .cs file with DependencyProperties. I understand I can create one just so I could use your solution, but it seems like an overkill, and I wonder if there's any more elegant solution to such a simple request.

Comment: I'll have another try at binding to a dependency property tonight.  However a simpler solution altogether would be to apply the logic in your multi-converter to the data before you bind to to the grid's ItemsSource.  Should be easy with a bit of Linq.

Comment: Hmm that's an interesting idea, even though it doesn't seem like a standard solution but more of an improvisation but maybe it will just do! I'll try that out, but still if there's an elegant solution, I would prefer it! Thanks!

Comment: Hey Phil, I've been thinking a bit about your solution and I've been wondering if using a Multi-Binding on the itemssource would not hurt performance as the itemssource would be set every time the DependencyProperty would change. And that may happen a lot as its actually a text field affected by the user. So suddenly I'm not sure that even this solution will hold. I just don't get it why they messed up the DataGrid so it doesn't work with an ElementName. Maybe I would just switch back to a ListView.

Comment: That would depend on the size of the collection. If the collection is in the 1000's it probably wouldn't take long, millions would be a problem.  You would have to test it.

Comment: You could optimize things by lazily evaluating the multi-binding logic when that property is first accessed in your data item.