# Insert Viewbox into DataGrid Cell

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to put something into a ViewBox and then this ViewBox would be added into the cell template of a DataGridTemplateColumn.All this was being done in code behind (C#).

I have done it with a Label,but I wanted to use a ViewBox.The code by using a Label is :

```
 DataGridTemplateColumn dgtc5 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

            dgtc5.Width = 142;
            dgtc5.Header = "Page Life Expectancy";
            DataTemplate dtemp5 = new DataTemplate();
            FrameworkElementFactory fef5 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));

Binding b5 = new Binding("PleChart");           
fef5.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, b5);

dtemp5.VisualTree = fef5;
dgtc5.CellTemplate = dtemp5;
```

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here [Binding a DataGrid's CellTemplate content to an Element or a DependencyProperty defined on the templated CustomControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415388/binding-a-datagrids-celltemplate-content-to-an-element-or-a-dependencyproperty/9457335#9457335).

Simply changing the data template like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="template2">
    <Viewbox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Funky: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomControl1}}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>
```

causes the contained text to grow/shrink to fit the viewbox.

Or simply do this:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```